# Trying to add geom points in bins to a plotly graph

Tags: r, r-plotly

I am trying to reproduce a **plotly** version of this **ggplot** graph.  It is a simple geom point with data bins of 7.  When I convert to plotly it puts all plots on one x axis.

I have tried using ggplotly function to convert.

Here is the code of the graph I am trying to reproduce.

```
p <-ggplot(EMdata3, aes(x=Team, y=`days waiting` ,binaxis='y',   stackdir='center',  dotsize=1, binwidth = 7 ))+  geom_dotplot(aes(fill = `RAG Rating`, color=`RAG Rating`),   binaxis='y',   stackdir='center',  dotsize=1, binwidth = 7) +  theme_minimal()
```

Which produces this:

[image]

However I need to use plotly to produce a similar graph, but for some reason when using ggplotly() to convert the plot does not plot on the x-axis and produces this instead:

[image]

How can I fix this and create a graph where the dots are in bins corresponding to the different locations?

I know there's a way to do it with jitter, but I want them to be uniform and not scattered across the x-axis.

Comment: Hi @Simon NHS, welcome to SO. External links to images are not a very good practice. Have fun coding!

Comment: this may be an open issue on github for plotly: https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1213